# How to reference existing SQLite db else create new DB and insert data?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, reference, exists

I am attempting to create a barcode scanner with a DB. If the database exists, add the data else create a new DB with the name "quantityCalculator.db" with the table name "quantityCalculator".

Have got some existing code but it is throwing up numerous errors in an attempt to fix/

Errors:

```
01-15 15:44:26.600: E/Trace(24862): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm7627a_JB_REL_RB1.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): Build Date: 01/18/13 Fri
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): Local Branch: 
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): Local Patches: NONE
01-15 15:44:27.350: I/Adreno200-EGL(24862): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
01-15 15:44:31.910: E/SQLiteLog(24862): (14) cannot open file at line 30178 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-15 15:44:31.910: E/SQLiteLog(24862): (14) os_unix.c:30178: (2) open(//foodcalculator.db) - 
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862): Failed to open database 'foodcalculator.db'.
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:197)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:485)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at com.example.quantitycalculator.AddItem.checkDataBase(AddItem.java:50)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at com.example.quantitycalculator.AddItem.onClick(AddItem.java:82)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17150)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/SQLiteDatabase(24862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 15:44:31.920: W/dalvikvm(24862): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c83498)
01-15 15:44:31.920: E/test(24862): Exception
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at com.example.quantitycalculator.AddItem.checkDataBase(AddItem.java:55)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at com.example.quantitycalculator.AddItem.onClick(AddItem.java:82)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17150)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
01-15 15:44:31.940: E/AndroidRuntime(24862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Homepage:**

```
package com.example.quantitycalculator;

import com.example.quantitycalculator.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Homepage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

        final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
        final Button editInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editItem);
        final Button currentInventoryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentItems);
        final Button settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddItem.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        currentInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CurrentItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        editInventoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditItems.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    static final class ProductData {
        String barcode;
        String title;
        Double quantity;
    }
}
```

**AddItem:**

```
package com.example.quantitycalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.quantitycalculator.R;

import com.example.quantitycalculator.Homepage.ProductData;

public class AddItem extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_BARCODE = 0;
    private static final ProductData mProductData = new ProductData();
    EditText mBarcodeEdit;
    EditText mTitleEdit;
    EditText mQuantityEdit;
    private Button mScanButton;
    private Button mAddButton;

    final String DATABASE_NAME = "quantitycalculator.db";
    final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.quantitycalculator.db";
    private final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "foodItems";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        mBarcodeEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.barcodeEdit);
        mTitleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEdit);
        mQuantityEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityEdit);
        mScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        mScanButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
            checkDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + PRODUCT_TABLE
                    + " (barcode String, title String, quantity Double);");
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scanButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);
            break;

        case R.id.addButton:
            String barcode = mBarcodeEdit.getText().toString();
            String title = mTitleEdit.getText().toString();
            String quantity = mQuantityEdit.getText().toString();

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            String errors = validateFields(barcode, title, quantity);
            if (errors.length() > 0) {
                showInfoDialog(this, "Please fix errors", errors);
            }

            if (checkDataBase() == false) {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                mProductData.barcode = barcode;
                mProductData.title = title;
                mProductData.quantity = Double.valueOf(quantity);

                checkDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " Values "
                        + (mProductData));
                checkDB.close();

                showInfoDialog(this, "Success", "Product saved successfully");
                resetForm();

            }

            else {
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                mProductData.barcode = barcode;
                mProductData.title = title;
                mProductData.quantity = Double.valueOf(quantity);

                checkDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " Values "
                        + (mProductData));
                checkDB.close();

                showInfoDialog(this, "Success", "Product saved successfully");
                resetForm();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showInfoDialog(Context context, String title,
            String information) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(information)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void resetForm() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mBarcodeEdit.getText().clear();
        mTitleEdit.getText().clear();
        mQuantityEdit.getText().clear();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_BARCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String barcode = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                mBarcodeEdit.setText(barcode);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private static String validateFields(String barcode, String title,
            String quantity) {
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

        if (barcode.matches("^\\s*$")) {
            errors.append("Barcode required\n");
        }

        if (title.matches("^\\s*$")) {
            errors.append("Title required\n");
        }

        if (!quantity.matches("^-?\\d+(.\\d+)?$")) {
            errors.append("Need numeric quantity\n");
        }

        return errors.toString();
    }
}
```

**Product Database:**

```
package com.example.quantitycalculator;

import com.example.quantitycalculator.Homepage.ProductData;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ProductDatabase {
    private static final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "foodItems";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quantitycalculator.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static class ProductDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String TAG = null;

        public ProductDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

            sql.append("create table ").append(PRODUCT_TABLE).append("(  ")
                    .append("   _id integer primary key,")
                    .append("   barcode text,").append("   title text,")
                    .append("   quantity number").append(")  ");

            db.execSQL(sql.toString());

            Log.d(TAG, PRODUCT_TABLE + "table created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + PRODUCT_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public ProductDatabase(Context context) {
        ProductDatabaseHelper helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(context);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public boolean insert(ProductData product) {
        ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
        vals.put("barcode", product.barcode);
        vals.put("title", product.title);
        vals.put("quantity", product.quantity);

        return db.insert(PRODUCT_TABLE, null, vals) != -1;
    }
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database folder is missing in your DATABASE_PATH .You should not hard code your database path 
 Change your DATABASE_PATH to this line:

```
DB_PATH="/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
```

Your logcat shows `Failed to open database 'foodcalculator.db'.` but in code I can see you are creating `quantitycalculator.db`. Please post the right logcat.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to mix database function with activity. You should create new classes to comunicate with database. You should read this tutorial, it will help you understand how design and create APP <-> DB interface in your application: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html